# ftp in ubuntu 12.04 lts to apache2 to edit the webpage

Tags: apache2

hello ive seen how to do this on ubuntu 10.10 and it did not work for me. So what im trying to accomplish is changing where the .html files go and how to get apache2 to read them, and have access to them with ftp.Answer ASAP if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can change where apache2 reads the files in each site's config file (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled).

In order to help you with the FTP-server we must know which ftp-server you're using.

Comment: no the ftp is into it from my laptop to edit and put webpages in.